# Python Flask Cors error - set according to documentation

Tags: python, flask

I have created API using Flask in Python. Now I am trying to create front end, where I want to call API. I set CORS according [Flask-Cors](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) documentation, unfortunately it doesn't work.

```
from flask_cors import CORS
CORS(app)
```

I got this error
[CORS error - Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvUDt.png)

[CORS error - Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICDRN.png)

I have found some similar topics, where was some solution. I have tried, but neither of them work for me. E.g.

```
CORS(app, origins=['http://localhost:4200'])
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'
```

I have also tried cross_origin decorator, but it doesn't work as well.

```
@app.route("/login", methods = ["POST"])
@cross_origin(origin='*')
def login():
    credentials = request.get_json()
    ....
```

Could someone help me, how to solve this problem?

Comment: Your client code must be specifying a URL that lacks a scheme/protocol to `fetch` or XHR; there lies the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the URL you are trying to access begins with `'http://'` or `'https://'` according to your web server's configuration